# Try To Set A BitMap In An Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I'm trying to set a BitMap here in a Fragment using the onCaptureImageResult() and onSelectFromGalleryResult() methods I created. Here is the code for that:

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    try {
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(data.getData().toString()).getContent()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
    //ivImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bm.getPath(data.getData())));
    try {
        ivImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(data.getData().toString()).getContent()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }

    // Check which request we're responding to
    System.out.println("Result: " + RESULT_OK + " " + resultCode);
    System.out.println("REQUEST CODE: " + EXIT_DIALOG + " " + requestCode);

    if (requestCode == EXIT_DIALOG) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + RESULT_OK + " " + resultCode);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.contentLayout, new LiveGameListFragment())
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
}
    private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}

private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
```

Originally I was using this line of code to set the BitMap to the ImageView:

```
ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

However this wasn't changing the image.  So then I went and modified that to this:

```
ivImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bm.getPath(data.getData())));
```

Here is what I'm seeing in the logcat:

```
07-31 20:42:11.262 31589-31589/com.movetheballsports.login E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-31 20:42:12.936 20069-20069/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
07-31 20:42:18.508 3234-3745/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'LABEL' not found
07-31 20:42:18.508 3234-3745/? E/NetlinkEvent: NetlinkEvent::FindParam(): Parameter 'UID' not found
07-31 20:42:24.591 5310-5478/? E/ContactsProvider_EventLog: Flush buffer to file cnt : 1 size : 0Kb duration : 3ms lastUpdatedAfter : 57978 ms mFlush_time_threasold : 2000 mCurrentSize : 465
```

Thinking I would get the path and be able to set the BitMap to the ImageView, however this didn't work either.  This is all being done in a Fragment.  Any suggestions on why this isn't working?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you seeing a stack trace?

Comment: Just added it to the question above.

Comment: Can you confirm that the path in `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bm.getPath(data.getData()))` valid and the result is not `null`? `if (bitmap != null){ Log.d(TAG, bitmap.getByteCount()) }` or similar.

Comment: I added that and it's not even getting to the Log statement.

Comment: It's not even getting to the onSelectFromGalleryResult() method.

Comment: What are you using to call the `onActivityResult()` method? This method is usually called when another Activity returns in a particular way.

Comment: I think the ones you are referring to are the galleryIntent() and the private void cameraIntent() methods.  I posted those above in the code if you want to take a look at them.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. Can you post that logs that show the `sysout` calls? And update your answer to include the bitmap logging that is not being hit. It sounds like the bitmap is either returning `null` (bad image data or bad path) or a method is not being called ( due to `resultCode` or `requestCode` isn't what is expected)

Comment: What do you mean by update my answer?  I don't have an answer as of right now.